# Merged xls output different

Tags: python, excel

I want the output of my script to be like :

```
2   11
4   12
6   13
8   14
48  15
```

But output comes like:

```
2   48
4   48
6   48
8   48
48  48
```

Below is the code, can somebody please help what I'm doing wrong:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import sys ; sys.path 
#Create workbook and worksheet

wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Data_1')#name of the sheet in which new data is there

row = 0

f = xlrd.open_workbook('Data_1.xls')#workbook from where data is extracted
g = xlrd.open_workbook('Data_2.xls')#workbook from where data is extracted

sheet1 = f.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet2 = g.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in xrange(5):
    temp = sheet1.row_values(i)
    print temp
    col = 0
    for element in temp:        
        sheet.write(i,col,element)
        col += 1
        i += 1

for j in xrange(5):
    temp1 = sheet2.row_values(j)
    print temp1
    col = 1
    for elements in temp1:
        sheet.write(j,col,element)
        col +=1
        j += 1

wbk.save('DATA.xls') #excel sheet name when saved in the folder
```

Comment: actually Data_1.xls contains "2
4
6
8
48
" in column one, while Data_2.xls contains "11
12
13
14
15
" in column one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second loop, you have a typo in the variable name.

```
for elements in temp1:
```

should be

```
for element in temp1:
```

---

**Edit**: You also have a lot of redundant code in your example. I took the liberty to rewrite your program to be a little more succinct (although note, I haven't tested this):

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import sys
#Create workbook and worksheet

wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
dest_sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Data_1')

for sheet_idx in range(1, 3):
  sheet = xlrd.open_workbook('Data_%d.xls' % sheet_idx).sheet_by_index(0)

  for i in range(5):
    values = sheet.row_values(i)
    for idx, element in enumerate(values):
      dest_sheet.write(i, sheet_idx+idx, element)

wbk.save('DATA.xls')
```

Comment: Thanks. I also edited my answer to shorten the OP's program by a bit.

Comment: This is fine when my ROW has just one element, but when there are 2 columns in row, my approach is not working. What I should do to get the output when Data_1.xls ROW 1 has 77 78, and same with Data_2.xls